# TemplateBinding on IsMouseOverBackground and IsPressedBackground

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm currently learning wpf, and I have created a generic style for all my buttons in App.xaml. In this style I've specify a template binding for the background in order to modify this property in specifics buttons of my app.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
      ...
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                         ... contentpresenter ...
                    </Border>
 ... end of style ...
```

Now I would like to do the same thing with IsMouseOverBackground and IsPressedBackground, I have already set the background values inside Trigger like below :

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverBackgroundColor}" />
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedBackgroundColor}" />
    </Trigger>

</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But I don't know  how I could put a TemplateBinding to this specific state of the button, And I would like to set those values on specific buttons of my app without create a style each time.

**Is it possible to do that without create my own DependencyProperty ?** ('No' is an acceptable response ^^)

**to sum up** I would like something as simple as that :

```
<Button Margin="0,0,0,1" Background="#FF2175A6" IsMouseOverBackground="#FF7021A6" IsPressedBackground="#FF21A639"/>
```

Thanks for replies ;)

Comment: is these `IsMouseOverBackground="#FF7021A6" IsPressedBackground="#FF21A639" are static?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you will have to use attached properties to achieve what you are trying:

Your class with attached properties:

```
public static class ButtonBackgrounds
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMouseOverBackground", typeof (Brush), typeof (ButtonBackgrounds), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

    public static void SetIsMouseOverBackground(UIElement element, Brush value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty, value);
    }

    public static Brush GetIsMouseOverBackground(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Brush) element.GetValue(IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPressedBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsPressedBackground", typeof (Brush), typeof (ButtonBackgrounds), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

    public static void SetIsPressedBackground(UIElement element, Brush value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsPressedBackgroundProperty, value);
    }

    public static Brush GetIsPressedBackground(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Brush) element.GetValue(IsPressedBackgroundProperty);
    }
}
```

then your XAML for setting backgrounds will look like:

```
<Button Content="Click Me!!" Margin="10" 
        local:ButtonBackgrounds.IsMouseOverBackground="#FF7021A6" 
        local:ButtonBackgrounds.IsPressedBackground="#FF21A639" />
```

and your style will become:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" 
                                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:ButtonBackgrounds.IsMouseOverBackground)}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" 
                                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:ButtonBackgrounds.IsPressedBackground)}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Refer to this MSDN page, [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on Attached Properties

Comment: So, the only way to solve the problem, would be to create a dependancy property ? If it is, you've answer perfectly to my question !

Comment: Hmm.. I missed _Is it possible to do that without create my own DependencyProperty ?_ part from your question :(

Comment: Yes, but your comment is still useful and appropriate. Thank you for that. It's maybe the only way but I find weird we've to writing all this code to proceed for such a simple thing ...